# LINQ Duplicate (un)tagging method

Tags: c#, linq

I've read a few ways to check for dups but in this case I need a property (IsDup) which is easy enough to set, but since both items (the equal objects) are both IsDup its harder to remove it from both once one of the two items is changed.

Here is the example code I have, but Im struggling with the groupby and count stuff. basically I want to look for any group (based on equality) of 1, meaning its partner (current) was changed and its IsDup is now false so i need to change this item to false as well.

I think the logic here is sound, im just struggling with the LINQ aspects

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {


        //current was a dup of the first item, which is why its set to true
        var current = new CustOb(){ prop1 = "prop1C", prop2 = "prop2C", IsDup=true};

        var list = new List<CustOb>();
        list.Add(new CustOb(){ prop1 = "prop1A", prop2 = "prop2A", IsDup=true});  //was a dup with current
        list.Add(new CustOb(){ prop1 = "prop1B", prop2 = "prop2B", IsDup=false});
        list.Add(new CustOb(){ prop1 = "imadup", prop2 = "dup", IsDup=true}); //this is here to make sure a real dup isnt reset
        list.Add(new CustOb(){ prop1 = "imadup", prop2 = "dup", IsDup=true}); //real dup
        list.Add(current);

        //code to be run on list item update

        //reset to false and recheck now that its been changed
        current.IsDup = false;

        //check to see if the 'current' item is a dup with anything in the list
        list.Where(o=>o.Equals(current)).Select(d => d.IsDup=true).ToArray();

        //look for any partners that are orphaned from this
        list.Where(o=> o.IsDup).GroupBy(x => x).Where(o=>o.Count() == 1).Select(o => o.IsDup = false);


        list.ForEach(o=>
            Console.WriteLine(o.prop1.ToString() + ", " + o.prop2.ToString() + ", " + o.IsDup.ToString())
        );
    }
}

public class CustOb
{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public string prop2 {get;set;}
    public bool IsDup {get;set;}
}
```

in the end what this should end up doing is setting all list item 1's isdup to false

Comment: You should implement your own method to determine equality.  Generally speaking .NET will use memory references to determine equality, and even if it didn't the 'IsDup' property is a variable you don't want hanging around in an equality check.  Also, unless you're expecting to have a ton of items in this list, just re-evaluate the entire list for duplicates, then check the 'IsDup' property on the item(s) you care about.  Your duplicate check shouldn't filter items based on previously known 'IsDup' statuses.

Comment: Im going to, but for the sake of this example I left that out. Also its unlikely there will be more than 200 items, the object themselves are not that complex, 10 properties or so. This will run on key press since of the properties its matched to is part of a WPF binding with updatesourcetrigger to propertychanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much screwing around I was able to get it to work with the following LINQ. Var names have been changed since this is what is used in the final app.

```
        //reset to false, and recheck for dups
        selectedProductConnection.IsDup = false;

        //check to see if the current item is a dup with anything in the list
        var dups = ProductConnections.Where(o => !ReferenceEquals(o, selectedProductConnection) && o.GetDupHash() == selectedProductConnection.GetDupHash());
        foreach (var pc in dups)
        {
            pc.IsDup = selectedProductConnection.IsDup = true;
        }

        //look for orphaned dup tags
        var grp = new HashSet<int>(
            ProductConnections.Where(o => o.IsDup)
                .GroupBy(o => o.GetDupHash())
                .Where(o => o.Count() == 1)
                .Select(a => a.Key));
        dups = ProductConnections.Where(x => grp.Contains(x.GetDupHash()));
        foreach (var pc in dups)
        {
            pc.IsDup = false;
        }
```

It could probably could be tweaked a bit, but im still really new to LINQ

I added a custom Hash on my object because in my real use case it doesnt compare the whole object, just certain fields. the custom hash is simply

```
return Host.GetHashCode() ^ Product.GetHashCode() ^ Vendor.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: That's super, man! Deleted my answer to highlight the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably update this in a minute, getting a little help on cleaning this up even more.